# How to install Doxygen on Qt creator

Tags: qt, qt-creator, doxygen

I need your help to install doxygen plugin on Qt creator. Many tutorials and videos suggest [this link](http://dev.kofee.org/projects/qtcreator-doxygen/wiki) to get it but it seems that it doesn't work anymore. Unfortunately, I didn't find any other.

I know [this one](http://www.doxygen.nl/download.html) will install doxygen but it will be done after installing the plugin.

I am not really good at installing programs so any tips will be welcomed. Thank you very much for your help.

Have a good day!

Answer (score 8):

You didn't mention what version of Creator you're using, so it may already be working. Try this:

1. in Creator, open one of your source files. (I'm assuming you're using C++.)
2. Navigate to a function definition, then use the arrow key to go to up one line.
3. Create a blank line (if necessary) then enter "/*!" and press enter.

You should see something like this appear:

```
/*!
 * \brief Nvs::Nvs
 * \param params
 */
Nvs::Nvs(Tasks *params)
{
```

If it doesn't, then your version of Creator isn't Doxygen enabled. I'd recommend an update to a newer version, but if you must use your current version, you'll need to follow the instructions here:

[Qt Doxygen Plugin](https://wiki.qt.io/Doxygen_Plugin_for_QtCreator)

Comment: Note the QT page mentions an old link to doxygen , this should be http://www.doxygen.nl/ and also on the Qt page the kofee link is broken.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. My version is 4.8.1 based on 5.12.0 (my bad for this oversight). I tried what you said and it works.
I already wrote the doxygen but I wrote @brief,@param... instead of \brief, \param... 
Is is a problem?

Comment: I've never seen syntax like @brief, etc, and I didn't see anything in my brief perusal of the doxygen page, but that doesn't mean it won't work. I'd try running the doxygen wizard and see what it produces.

Comment: Sorry for my late reply.
@brief,@param work when I start with ' /** '.
I got your version (\brief,\param...) when I write ' /*! '
My way to do works with the link from albert (thank you by the way).
I don't know if there is a real difference.

Comment: The syntax /*! is the "Qt" way of doing it. If you're planning on sticking with Qt, I'd recommend it. But either syntax should generate Doxygen files.